# Show only a piece of a text that is inside a variable

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have this code:

```
data = {
   date: '01/01/01 - My Name'
}


<% for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
    <td> <%= data[i].date %>   </td> // I want show just the date here
    <td> <%= data[i].date %>   </td> // I want show just the name here
<% } %>
```

How can i show just the date in the first td, and just the name in the second?

Yes, i now i can separete the two, but i can't do that.. this is just a example for what i need, in the right circumstances i cant do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can simply use `split(' - ')` to create array from the string

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var dateParts = data[i].date.split(' - '); // returns ['01/01/01', 'My Name']
 %>
    <td> <%= dateParts[0] %>   </td> // I want show just the date here
    <td> <%= dateParts[1] %>   </td> // I want show just the name here
<% } %>
```

Assumes there is a space before and after `-` as shown in sample